# Fastest sort for small collections

Tags: java, sorting, collections

Many times I have to sort large amounts of small lists, arrays. It is quite rare that I need to sort large arrays. Which is the fastest sort algorithm for sorting:

- arrays
- (array)lists

of size 8-15 elements of these types:

- integer
- string from 10-40 characters

?

I am listing element types because some algorithms do more compare operations and less swap operations.

I am considering Merge Sort, Quick Sort, Insertion Sort and Shell sort (2^k - 1 increment).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Arrays.sort(..)` / `Collections.sort(..)` will make that decision for you.

For example, the [openjdk-7 implementation of `Arrays.sort(..)`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/DualPivotQuicksort.java.html) has `INSERTION_SORT_THRESHOLD = 47` - it uses insertion sort for those with less than 47 elements.

Comment: Exactly, and for small collections, the difference in efficiency is hardly noticeable anyway on modern machines.

Comment: I expected the answer that "it doesn't matter". It does matter when the server is servicing few dozen requests per second with few dozen sorts each. Merge sort produces a lot of allocations and thus makes garbage collector work harder. Is this insertion sort threshold in Sun/Oracle Java 6 implementation? If not it does little to help me.

Comment: You can check the Java 6 code for what exactly the threshold is. But the algorithm is specified long ago, so I don't expect any major difference.

Comment: Checked out my particular implementation (IBM java 6) - threshold is 7.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you can prove that this is a bottleneck then the built in sorts are fine:

```
Collections.sort(myIntList);

Arrays.sort(myArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there isn't a universal answer.  Among other things, the performance of a Java sort algorithm will depend on the relative cost of the compare operation, and (for some algorithms) on the order of the input.  In the case of a list, it also depends on the list implementation type.

But @Bozho's advice is sound, as is @Sean Patrick Floyd's comment.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

If you believe that the performance difference is going to be significant for your use-case, then you should get hold of some implementations of different algorithms, and test them out using the actual data that your application needs to deal with.  (And if you don't have the data yet, it is too soon to start tuning your application, because the sort performance will depend on actual data.)

In short, you'll need to do the benchmarking yourself.